# Считывание из nfg файла при помощи fscanf_s

Tags: c++, файлы

```
fopen_s(&pFile, "House.nfg", "r+");
for (;i < 100;++i) {
    fscanf_s(pFile, " %*d. pos:[%f, %f, %f]; norm:[%*f, %*f, %*f]; binorm:[%*f, %*f, %*f]; tgt:[%*f, %*f, %*f]; uv:[%f, %f];",
        &verticesData[i].pos.x, &verticesData[i].pos.y, &verticesData[i].pos.z, &verticesData[i].uv.x, &verticesData[i].uv.y);
    ++i;
}
```

формат текста в файле NrVertices: 170

```
  0. pos:[-881.551086, -0.000000, 955.795349]; norm:[0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000]; binorm:[0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000]; tgt:[1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000]; uv:[0.014965, 0.006930];

   1. pos:[763.035583, -0.000000, 955.795349]; norm:[0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000]; binorm:[0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000]; tgt:[1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000]; uv:[0.529346, 0.006930];
```

Comment: Вопрос-то, собственно, в чем?

Comment: не считывает собственно

Answer (score 1):

Начните с проверок

1. Открывается ли файл (не нулевое ли значение `pFile` после открытия).
2. Чему равно начальное значение `i`? В цикле оно не инициализировано - может, оно на входе уже равно 1000 :)
3. Зачем у вас ДВА инкремента `i` - в заголовке цикла и в теле?

После этого посмотрим, что делать дальше (если это дальше вообще потребуется).